# json data to render in <TableRow> in react

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to render a `tableData` of a format like:
[image]

in a `<TableRow>` like :

```
{this.state.tableData.map((row, index) => (
          <TableRow key={index}>
            <TableRowColumn>{console.log(tableData[index].name)}{tableData[index].name}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{tableData[index].role}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{tableData[index].phone}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{tableData[index].email}</TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
          ))}
```

the console in the code snippet is giving me the correct value I can check in the browser.

[image]

But the code snippet `<TableRowColumn>{tableData[index].name}</TableRowColumn>`
is giving the error `Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

any suggestion please!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, you should call table data with `this.state.tableData` in rows too, not with `tableData[index]`, because `tableData` is undefined. But I would recommend you to use `row` variable which you have inside the `map` function.

Comment: using row, how can I render the value in that case, as I am receiving data in a Array of json format.
[{"userId":"User8","password":null,"name":"User8","role":"role8","phone":"9874020208","email":"rta8@ericsson.com","msg":null,"statusCode":201},{"userId":"User0","password":null,"name":"User0","role":"role0","phone":"9874020200","email":"rta0@ericsson.com","msg":null,"statusCode":201},{"userId":"User3","password":null,"name":"User3","role":"role3","phone":"9874020203","email":"rta3@ericsson.com","msg":null,"statusCode":201}]

Comment: row.name, and why do you paste a block of json in a comment?

Comment: Just replace tableData[index] with row. You have array of objects, with map function you get a single object from that array, which is stored inside row variable. Then you access it's fields like row.name, row.password.

Comment: @flq: I am trying to express the format the way I am getting the data.